# displaying multiple image using ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I want to display multiple images once I get response from ajax, but when I am iterating through the for each loop, it only display first image not the all image.

```html
<body onload="showMultiplePhotos()">
  <div class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid">
    <div class="img-zoom-container text-center">
      <a href="#" class="previous">&laquo; Previous</a>
      <span id="viewuploadedImage"><%= UserDetails.getInstance().getimageName() %></span>
      <span id="search-result"></span>
      <a href="#" class="next">Next &raquo;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col text-center">
        <button class="btn clsBtn" onclick="window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();">Close    Window</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```js
function bigImageRequest() {
  var action = $('#view').attr('value');
  var url = "bigImage"
  $('.loader').show();
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      url: url,
      action: action,
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $('.loader').hide();
      let elem;
      let cntid = 0;
      var totalNumberOfImage = response.length;
      var successUrl = "./bigImage.jsp?id=" + response[0].userID;
      window.open(successUrl, "_blank");
      $('#viewuploadedImage').html(response.uploadedImage);
      $('#container').append(response.uploadedImage);
      $(response).each(function(i, element) {
        $('#search-result').html(response.userPhoto);
      })
    },
    error: function(jqxhr) {
      $('.loader').hide();
      alert("Something went wrong. Please logout and re-try again after login.");
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

As a response, I am getting below response and I am show userPhoto response on the page:

```js
[{
  userPhoto: "<img alt='img' src='data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQ…op' border='1' style='width:100%;height:auto;'/> ",
  userID: "7570b164-19e4-4561-b17e-f7f7e1c68f75"
}, {
  userPhoto: "<img alt='img' src='data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQ…op' border='1' style='width:100%;height:auto;'/> ",
  userPhotoID: "44"
}, {
  userPhoto: "<img alt='img' src='data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQ…op' border='1' style='width:100%;height:auto;'/> ",
  userPhotoID: "48"
}]
```

Comment: I am using loop here it is:$(response).each(function(i,element){
            $('#search-result').html(response.userPhoto);

        }) You can also see in the above code.. if it is wrong, can you please suggest me in correcting it?

Comment: To help you we need to know what the full content of `response` is

Comment: this is the resposne, I am getting: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {userPhoto: "<img alt='img' src='data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQ…op' border='1' style='width:100%;height:auto;'/> ", userID: "7570b164-19e4-4561-b17e-f7f7e1c68f75"}
1: {userPhoto: "<img alt='img' src='data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQ…op' border='1' style='width:100%;height:auto;'/> ", userPhotoID: "44"}
2: {userPhoto: "<img alt='img' src='data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQ…op' border='1' style='width:100%;height:auto;'/> ", userPhotoID: "48"}
length: 3

Comment: Just a guess, but `$('#search-result').html(response.userPhoto)` should probably be changed to `$('#search-result').append(element.userPhoto)`. Take another look at what your current code is doing - i.e. calling `.html()` with the same value in each iteration.

Comment: Please use the `edit` button under the question to add information. Code in comments is unreadable

Comment: added response in the question

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: `response.uploadedImage` isn't in your response output.

Comment: I've tried with response.userPhoto as well but it only lists one photo not the entire list of photos. Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You need use [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) method of jquery to `insert` content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.Working example :

```js
//Your json response
var res=[ 
   { 
      userPhoto:"<img alt='img' src='data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQ…op' border='1' style='width:100%;height:auto;'/> ",
      userID:"7570b164-19e4-4561-b17e-f7f7e1c68f75"
   },
   { 
      userPhoto:"<img alt='img' src='data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQ…op' border='1' style='width:100%;height:auto;'/> ",
      userPhotoID:"44"
   },
   { 
      userPhoto:"<img alt='img' src='data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQ…op' border='1' style='width:100%;height:auto;'/> ",
      userPhotoID:"48"
   }
];

//looping through result
res.forEach(function(obj) {
//appending images to div with id search-result
$('#search-result').append(obj.userPhoto); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-result"></div>
```

---

**Update** :
You can append all image in some  variable and then use `.html` to add that in particular div .Working example :

```js
//Your json response
var res=[ 
   { 
      userPhoto:"<img alt='img' src='data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQ…op' border='1' style='width:100%;height:auto;'/> ",
      userID:"7570b164-19e4-4561-b17e-f7f7e1c68f75"
   },
   { 
      userPhoto:"<img alt='img' src='data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQ…op' border='1' style='width:100%;height:auto;'/> ",
      userPhotoID:"44"
   },
   { 
      userPhoto:"<img alt='img' src='data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQ…op' border='1' style='width:100%;height:auto;'/> ",
      userPhotoID:"48"
   }
];
var append_image="";
//looping through result
res.forEach(function(obj) {
//appending images 

append_image+=obj.userPhoto; 
});
//add to div
$('#search-result').html(append_image);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-result"></div>
```

Comment: This is appending on the same page, but I am opening a new tab and this new image should get load on that new tab.

Comment: I was not knowing that , now check updated answer ,let me know if it works or not .

Comment: success: function(response){ 
   $('.loader').hide();
   let elem;
      let cntid = 0;
   var totalNumberOfImage = response.length;
   var successUrl = "./bigImage.jsp?id="+response[0].userID; 
   var w= window.open(successUrl,"_blank")
   window.focus();
   var append_image="";
   response.forEach(function(obj) {
    append_image+=obj.userPhoto; 
    });
    $('#search-result').html(append_image); 
   
   
  },
  error: function(jqxhr) {
   $('.loader').hide();
   alert("Something went wrong. Please logout and re-try again after login.");
   return false;
  }
 });
}

Comment: what does it show on new tab? only one image ,because i have tested above code it is working successfully for new tab.